# objective-c change width of custom image view object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, image, view, object

I have 3 buttons on my main view named btn_easy, btn_medium, and btn_hard that I would like to make change the width of two custom image view objects named racquet_green, and racquet_yellow upon clicking.

The code I have to start the executing of the method upon button click is:

```
   -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
      UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
    if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"easy"]){
        NSLog(@"easy clicked");
            //change width of racquet_green and racquet_yellow to 100px
      }
      if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"medium"]){
        NSLog(@"medium clicked");
            //change width of racquet_green and racquet_yellow to 60px
      }
      if([button.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"hard"]){
        NSLog(@"hard clicked");
           //change width of racquet_green and racquet_yellow to 40px
      }
   }
```

can someone please help me figure out how to change the width of these custom view objects?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   [racquet_yellow setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,35,5)];
   [racquet_green setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,35,5)];
```

works perfectly but wait - I also want to make the paddles centered on the top and bottom of the view. I did that by adding 2 lines below the lines posted above.

```
[racquet_yellow setFrame:CGRectMake(((self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-(racquet_yellow.bounds.size.width/2)),self.view.bounds.size.height-20,50,5)];
[racquet_green setFrame:CGRectMake(((self.view.bounds.size.width/2)-(racquet_green.bounds.size.width/2)),15,50,5)];
```

I have to do this with 4 lines rather than 2 because if I set the x,y position before I set the width of the paddles then the x,y position is slightly off.  So, we set the width,height first then the x,y keeping width and height because we don't want to set it back to 0,0.

Answer (score 1):

```
rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, PixelsX, PixelsY);
[myView setFrame:rect];
```

Comment: where myView is the racquet_green and racquet_yellow image views?

Comment: Yep, myView was just a placeholder

Comment: this doesn't work, first an error is thrown saying that rect is undefined.  So I go up to the top of my code and add #define rect 64.  (64 is the default pixels).  After doing that I get an error for the rect = CGRectMake line saying "Lvalue required as left operand of assignment" and the [racquet_yellow setFrame:rect]; line throws an error saying "Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'setFrame:'"

Comment: rect has to be from type CGRect. No reason to vote me down just because I didn't wrote it, you can look into the manual to see what CGRectMake creates and from what kind te UIView frame ivar is.

Comment: I've added the syntax: CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,64,5); but I get an error saying "Expected identifier or '(' before numeric constant. what am I missing here?